# localhost working fine but heroku app give cors error

Tags: heroku, cors, localhost

```
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: [ "GET", "POST" ]
    }
})
```

this code run on localhost 5000 but when deploy into heroku then client side give cors error

( Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mysterious-citadel-77081.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NzgoLxf' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. )

Comment: When you ran the Express server locally, both the development web server and the Express server ran on host `localhost`, hence no cross-origin requests. Now your Express server is running on some other host (`mysterious-citadel-77081.herokuapp.com`), hence cross-origin request issues. You will need to explicitly [permit CORS](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

Comment: @Zulfe Brother how can i add explicitly permit with cors in my app

Comment: Just to mention, if you are on localhost, but on a different port, it is treated as CORS.